# Contour plot for a likelihood function

Tags: r, normal-distribution, data-visualization

For the likelihood associated with the mixture model

`1/4*Normal(mu1,1)+3/4*Normal(mu2,1)`

I would like to have a figure as like as following one for a simulated sample of 500 observation from `mu1=0` and `mu2=2.5`. My `R` code is:

```
da=rbind(rnorm(10^2),2.5+rnorm(4*10^2))  
like=function(mu1,mu2){  
sum(log((.25*dnorm(da-mu1)+.75*dnorm(da-mu2))))}  
mmu1=seq(-2,5,length.out=length(da))  
mmu2=seq(-2,5,length.out=length(da))  
post=outer(mmu1,mmu2,like)    
image(mmu1,mmu2,post,xlab=expression(mu1),ylab=expression(mu2)) 
contour(mmu1,mmu2,post,add=T)
```

which contains the error:

```
"Error in dnorm(da-mu1): 
dims [product 800] do not match the length of object"
```

I've changed the length of `mmu1` & `mmu2`, but nothing seemed
to be happening.
Could someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `outer` does not work the way you want. When you call `outer` it passes to the function `like` the vectors and expects the vector as a result. In your case your function expects the scalars and returns the scalar. Try changing it to something similar to this:

```
like <- function(mu1,mu2) {
    apply(cbind(mu1,mu2),1,function(x)sum(log((.25*dnorm(da-x[1])+.75*dnorm(da-x[2])))))  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As outer() expects that the function you pass in is vectorized, change your line to

```
post=outer(mmu1,mmu2,Vectorize(like))
```

to get

[image]